# Sort Index of data frame alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot, graph

I am reading in a data frame from a csv file and I am trying to create a time graph of when the tickets were issued by the frequency of tickets issued. The column containing the times is set in a format of hours with a letter indicating am or pm i.e 1200A. Because of this when I try sorting the data frame in ascending order only the numerical value is considered and the A, P is disregarded. How can I sort the index of my data frame to consider the A and P

I have tried using `sort_index`
 function and this works but only in sorting the numbers

```
from matplotlib 
import pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
tickets = pd.read_csv("./Parking_Violations_Issued_-_Fiscal_Year_2019.csv")

d2=tickets['Violation Time'].value_counts()
df2=d2.sort_index(ascending=1, sort_remaining='true')
```

**Sample dataset:**

```
Index  Violation Time
.847A   1
0000A   801
0000P   22
0001A   545
0001P   1
0002A   499
0003A   520
0004A   498
0004P   1
0005A   619
0006A   983
0007A   993
0008A   1034
0008P   1
0009A   1074
```

Original CSV [link](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Parking-Violations-Issued-Fiscal-Year-2019/faiq-9dfq)

Comment: @shaikmoeed I don't think my column is in any official form. It doesn't have a standard form like DD-MM-YYYY for example for date

Answer (score 1):

This will do your job.

**Explanation:**

- First, I converted your time column with tuple, like `[('.847', 'A'), ('0000', 'A'), ('0001', 'A') ...`
- Next, I have sorted according to your logic i.e., `second element('A', 'P') of tuple and then first element(numbers)` and Joined those tuples to get back to its original state.
- Finally merged with the original dataset to get required output.

**Code:**

```
>>> tickets # Assuming your initial dataframe looks like below, as mentioned in OP
    Index  Violation Time
0   .847A          1  
1   0000A        801   
2   0000P         22   
3   0001A        545   
4   0001P          1   
5   0002A        499   
6   0003A        520   
7   0004A        498   
8   0004P          1   
9   0005A        619   
10  0006A        983   
11  0007A        993   
12  0008A       1034   
13  0008P          1   
>>> final_df = pd.DataFrame(["".join(i) for i in sorted(tickets.apply(lambda x: (x['Index'][:-1], x['Index'][-1]), axis=1), key=lambda x : (x[1], x[0]))])
>>> df2.rename(columns={0:'Index'}, inplace=True)
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> final_df.merge(tickets)
    Index  Violation Time
0   .847A          1   
1   0000A        801   
2   0001A        545   
3   0002A        499   
4   0003A        520   
5   0004A        498  
6   0005A        619   
7   0006A        983   
8   0007A        993   
9   0008A       1034   
10  0009A       1074   
11  0000P         22   
12  0001P          1   
13  0004P          1   
14  0008P          1
```

Comment: I get error  `<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: @Kayla You are wrongly closing parenthesis of lambda. I suggest to copy-paste the code or recheck once again.

Comment: @Kayla If it solved your question, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: mooed `df3 = pd.DataFrame(["".join(i) for i in sorted(df2.apply(lambda x: (x['Index'][:-1], x['Index'][-1]), axis=1), key=lambda x : (x[1], x[0]))])
df3.rename(columns={0:'Index'}, inplace=True)
df3.merge(df2)` this is my exact code, what am I missing??

Comment: @Kayla You are using `df2` in `sorted(df2.apply...`. Change it to `sorted(df.apply...` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: What is `df` in your actual program, I see that there are three `df's`?

Comment: the original dataset is 'tickets', please look at the code I have written from my question. I am unsure of if you want me to use df2 or d2 or tickets @shaik

Comment: Changed the code according to your naming convention. Please check now.

Comment: I don't think you are referencing the column that needs to be sorted which is 'Violation Time', that is why I made a new data frame with this as the index and assigned this to d2. I get error: ('Index', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @Kayla Can you please add expected output for the sample dataset posted in question?

Comment: The output you posted is the correct output, I see the problem now, the 'index' is not the name of the column, it is the actual index instead of 0,1,2,3,...n. Is there a way to use your code considering this? @shaik

Comment: @Kayla You can rename the column as you want and use it. But, I don't think, that will be an issue, in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing an algorithm to parse the time strings into the sorting order you would like.

If indeed every `Violation Time` has an A or P at the last character, you could create a new sorting column which parses the time string into a datetime object. Depending on how dirty the data is, you will have to add some additional parsing checks for the hour and minute substrings, but here is a good start:

EDIT: I added in checks for length and string type to ensure the string is parseable before parsing.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
def parseDateTime(x, tformat='%I%M%p'):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return None
    if type(x) is str and len(x) == 5:
        if x[0:2].isdigit() and x[2:4].isdigit():
            newString = str(x).strip() + 'M'
            parsedDateTime = datetime.strptime(newString,tformat)
            return parsedDateTime
    else:
        return None
```

Note that without date information, the times will all be treated as being on the same day.

Now, you can apply this function to the column and then use the new parsed column for your sorting purposes.

```py
tickets['Violation Time Parsed'] = tickets['Violation Time'].apply(parseDateTime)
```

Comment: I get error time data 'nanM' does not match format '%I%M%p', some of my rows contain no data and some (very few) do not contain a P or A

Comment: Depending on how dirty the data is, you will have to add some additional parsing checks for the hour and minute substrings.

Comment: what conditional would I use if I were putting the data in a new data frame? for example: newdf=tickets[tickets['Violation Time'] == conditional]

Comment: Using the parser above, you could use datetime functionality to check hour and minute. Something like t[ ((t['vtime'].dt.hour == 12) & (t['vtime'].dt.minute == 0)) ]

Comment: Note that times are converted to military time, so to check for 2:00PM you'd check hour == 14